# How to convert local time into GMT time zone in Python

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, gmt

Input:

```
datetime.now().time()
```

I need to covert this time into GMT format in python

Can anyone help me for this?

Comment: What is GMT format? UTC is GMT normally...

Comment: @MrFuppes Like present IST time needs to convert into (GMT+05:30) format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "convert" you mean format to string with a certain suffix.

Option 1: localize to your machine's time zone and strftime:

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.now().astimezone(None).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
# I'm on CET so this gives me
# '2020-11-30 13:43:15 GMT+0100'
```

Option 2: localize to specific time zone - and stftime:

```
# Python 3.9: from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo
from dateutil.tz import gettz # Python <3.9

datetime.now(gettz("Asia/Kolkata")).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S GMT%z")
# '2020-11-30 18:14:54 GMT+0530'
```

Comment: Instead of GMT%z i need to pass argument like GMT+5:30 or GMT-5:00 like this , is that possible ?

Comment: @AswathyMA: not sure I understand what you actually want to do. Do you want to convert a datetime from one to another time zone?

Comment: @ MrFuppes : Yes...Eg : I want to convert IST time into (GMT+5:30) format .